# how to reach database fields from default.ctp in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm unable to show a db field value in default.ctp , like unreaded messages or username , 
I keep getting Undefined variable: user, or message

how to reach them from default.ctp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your default layout is application wide, you will need to process data in the AppController.php in the beforeFilter method, so something like this

In AppController.php  :

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    //for example, you want to read messages
    //import the Model
    $this->loadModel('Message');
    $all_messages = $this->Message->find('all'); //or whatever you need to do to get the data
    $this->set('all_messages', $all_messages); 
}
```

Then in your default.ctp,call the variable: $all_messages